# connect Apple Store Connect API app to rails backend

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, react-native

I have an app build with react native and ruby on rails as backend. We deployed ios reactnative app to testflight. We can't figure how to connect ruby on rails api to ios app on testflight?

I have generate App Store Connect API key. not sure how to use the key.

Comment: What actually you want to do? Because [App Store Connect API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi) is for automate tasks on the Apple Developer website and App Store Connect.

Comment: @ŁukaszŁabuński i want to know how to connect ios app which is build on react native to rails backend so the data can flow between the app and the database

Comment: So you need to do [API calls](https://reactnative.dev/docs/network) in your application before uploading app to TestFlight because [TestFlight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/) is for BETA testing.